# SharePoint Online Throttling

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom

We are creating a custom solution using SharePoint CSOM.

There are some cases where we need to store ~400 list items containing Attachments, with a total size of about 400 MB.

We are uploading them in parallel (using TPL library, each iteration using a new instance of ClientContext object) so the whole process of uploading them does not take that much time. However, we receive a lot of throttling errors (HTTP STATUS CODE 429).

We did some research and found that setting the User-Agent header [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-avoid-getting-throttled-or-blocked-in-sharepoint-online) could partially solve the throttling issue, but it's not that clear what values (extracted from where?) you need to use in order to compose the header.

Any idea how we can avoid getting throttled because the main flows in the app require uploading a large number of documents or storing a large number of list items at once?

Comment: You need to make the User-Agent link up, `ctx.ExecutingWebRequest += delegate (object sender, WebRequestEventArgs e)
    {
        e.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.UserAgent = "NONISV|YourCompany|YourProductName/1.0";
    };`

Comment: "YourCompany" & "YourProductName" need to be extracted from somewhere? Or they can be random values?

Comment: YourCompany = name of your company (assuming you work in a company or for a company), YourProductname = name of the product you are creating.

Comment: I got this, but should these values be registered somewhere "officially" like a SharePoint app ?

Comment: No, you don't need to register them.